# Why isn't Angular's `$location.url` working after my Bootstrap Modal close?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, mean-stack

## Problem:

Anyone know why in my `cb.register` function below, my Modal window closes OK, but the `$location.url('/dashboard')` does not properly run?

I don't get any console errors, and the page does not redirect. However, `console.log('TRANSITION DONE')` still prints out in the code below after the modal window closes, so I know the event is being recognized:

### Code:

```
app.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'userFactory', '$location', function($scope, userFactory, $location) {
    var cb = {
        register: function(createdUser) {
            // Closes Modal window:
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            // Runs after close with completed transition effects:
            $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                console.log('TRANSITION DONE');
                $location.url('/dashboard');
            })
        },
    };

}]);
```

## Questions:

- Why does the `$location` service not behave properly when nested inside of my `.on()` function?
- Should I be using `angular-ui` instead? (Of which I was not familiar until researching solutions to this issue, and instead started my project by framing out all the views first using bootstrap3 and including the JS files, etc).

#### What I've Tried:

- I've tried passing the `$location` parameter into the `.on()`'s callback function, along with `e`, but that made no real change and the function should still have access to `$location` in the larger scope.
- Console logging `$location` or `$location.url` works properly, so I know the methods are accessible in the scope.
- Moving the `$location` function outside of the `on()` function does load the dashboard page, however the fade-out modal close does not complete. A light-grey transparent BG is overlaying my dashboard page, which is why I chose to utilize the `hidden.bs.modal` event per the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

  ```
  // Closes window:
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  // Redirects to page but fade-out on Modal not completed:
  $location.url('/dashboard');
  ```

#### Desired Behavior/Pseudo-Code:

- Modal window closes (when callback runs)
- After Modal fade out:

  - `$location.url('/dashboard')` runs, loading dashboard page

Thank you to any angular/bootstrap ninjas whom can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does the $location service not behave properly when nested inside of my .on() function?**

You're directly using Bootstrap modals in your application -- which is OK. *But*, this requires you to manipulate the modal with jQuery. It is not advisable to use jQuery in an AngularJS application as AngularJS has its own methods of DOM manipulation and therefore you shouldn't manually manipulate the DOM via jQuery.

To answer your question, since you're using jQuery to directly manipulate the DOM, it is likely that AngularJS' digest cycle has not picked up on the modal closing. You could get around this by telling AngularJS to activate a digest cycle via `$scope.$apply()`. However, this will easily dirty up your code and just doesn't make sense according to best AngularJS principles.

**Should I be using angular-ui instead? (Of which I was not familiar until researching solutions to this issue, and instead started my project by framing out all the views first using bootstrap3 and including the JS files, etc).**

Yes. I would *highly* suggest using [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). As per the documentation:

> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required.

As you can see, all of the Bootstrap functionality has been wrapped up into AngularJS directives that can easily be dropped into your application without worrying about jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and thorough response, very very helpful! I should have known there could be some conflict between how Angular and jQuery each manipulate the DOM. So far I've framed out all my HTML using bootstrap CSS to build the elements...will be reading the documentation and will swap out the bootstrap dependencies for `angular-ui`'s and adjust my views...looks like there is a `$close` (angular-ui) function which can close a modal and pass a result..I will read docs and research and play around..thank you again, makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: Did have one clarification question: So basically it's bad practices to use jQuery within an Angular Controller (like I did), since there are conflicts (thus the creation of `angular-ui`), is that right? It's never appropriate to do so, is that right (ie, angular's digest cycle)? Thanks again, learning my way through over here!

Comment: @natureminded You're welcome. It seems like you have a good grasp on this concept, so should I explain a bit a more. It is _generally_ bad practice to use any direct DOM manipulation in an AngularJS controller. I wouldn't say never do it. There are always weird use cases where it could be acceptable to directly manipulate the DOM if there is no other way around your problem. Likewise, you _could_ use third party jQuery libraries in your AngularJS application if you understand the implications of doing so.

Comment: @natureminded The same thing really applies with `$scope.$apply()`. It is convenient that AngularJS allows us to interact with the digest cycle, but you should know when to do this. You don't want to always rely on this method if your data bindings aren't updating or your routing isn't working (in your case). If you find yourself using `$scope.$apply()` I would first ask yourself if there's another way to do this or if you're doing something wrong. Also, doing this can get you into some pretty nasty infinite digest cycle loops.

Comment: I appreciate the added response. I definitely want to work within how the framework was designed, and not "ghetto rig" it (as the colloquial phrase goes :D)..I see what you're saying about case-specific reasons to use jQuery...This was my first time trying to bring bootstrap into an angular project, and for some reason I didn't even think about the DOM manipulation and the potential conflicts that could have arisen. I have more to learn about how angular manipulates the DOM behind the scenes...Thanks for the encouragement to do things the right way and for the extra information!